# Ma'ayanah Shel Torah on the Festivals and 613 Mitzvot?

Tags: jewish-books, acharonim

On the [title page of Ma'ayanah Shel Torah](http://hebrewbooks.org/41776), it says that the series covers the Parshiot, Haftarot, Festivals, and 613 Commandments. [I have the 5 volumes on the Parshiot and Haftarot](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx?title=&auth=%25u05E4%25u05E8%25u05D9%25u05D3%25u05DE%25u05DF%2C%20%25u05D0%25u05DC%25u05DB%25u05E1%25u05E0%25u05D3%25u05E8%20%25u05D6%25u05D5%25u05E9%25u05D0&ocr=&sort=0#gsc.tab=0), but they do not cover the Festivals. There is no section for the 613 Commandments either, but some are covered in the Parsha.

Is there a Ma'ayanah Shel Torah on the Festivals?

Comment: Possibly it includes yom tov next to the parshiyos they fall around?

Comment: @user3949142: nope.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly not. The [Hebrew](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9F) and [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Zusia_Friedman) Wikipedia articles say that תורה קוואל and its translation מעינה של תורה cover the *parashiyos* and *haftaros*, implying that those are the only sections.

Those are all `hebrewbooks.org` has, too.